# Why does the PHPSESSID in the cookie change after refreshing the page？

Tags: php, session, cookies

I found that `session_start()` changed the `PHPSESSID` in the cookie, because without it, the `PHPSESSID` in the cookie will not change.

But the expected result should be that after refreshing the page, `session_start ()` will not change the `PHPSESSID` in the cookie and I got the correct result when deploying the same code file to another server.

Another point that confuses me is that in the server in question, the value of `PHPSESSID` in the set-cookie value of the response header every time the page is refreshed is an unchanged, correct value.

I find that if I set `session.auto_start = 1` then the problem is solved.However,I need to call `session_save_path()` before `session_start()` so that sessions won't be saved in the tmp directory.I don't know why when I call `session_start ()` manually, the error occurs on this server, but it works fine on other servers.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061324/2310830

Comment: DId you check `session.cookie_lifetime`

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045550/php-session-id-changes-between-pages

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you. I find that if I set `session.auto_start = 1` then the problem is solved.However,I need to call `session_save_path` before `session_start` so that sessions won't be saved in the tmp directory.I don't know why when I call `session_start ()` manually, the error occurs on this server, but it works fine on other servers.

Comment: This all seems to be config oriented, So basically the servers are not configured the same.

Comment: session_save_path is also configured in `php.ini`

Comment: Okay, just one more question,can I configure different session_save_path in php.ini for different sites？