# PHP session is not resuming

Tags: php, session, session-variables, cloudflare, resume

I have a problem with sessions in PHP. When I use `session_start()`, and assign a value using `$_SESSION['x'] = "Y"`, the value is gone after refreshing the page (session is empty). `echo session_id();` always shows a different value. I also tried using `exit()` after assigning the value. This probably means that the session is not resumed, a new one is created instead. What can I do?

**EDIT:** I am using cloudflare, might this be a problem?

My code:

```php
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
exit();
```

It always shows something different. PHP session is created in /var/lib/php/sessions, but php session cookie is not set, cookies are enabled in my browser. I have also tried a different browser.

**EDIT 2:**
When I refresh the page, a new session file is created.
The only cookie is `__cfduid`. I think it's something with cloudflare.

**EDIT 3:**
I have also tried without cloudflare. My PHP sessions settings are default.

Comment: Can you share your entire code?

Comment: @Will 

`<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
exit();`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306713/php-session-id-changing-on-every-request

Comment: `session_id()` showing a different value is problematic. It should be empty if not set. Does a PHP session cookie get created in the browser?

Comment: @user3783243 it is not. The only cookie is __cfduid, I think it's something with cloudflare.

Comment: 1. Have you tested without Cloudflare? 2. Have you double-checked your [php.ini session settings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)?

Comment: @MarkusAO I have tested without cloudflare, I havn't change my session settings since I installed PHP. Which settings should I change?

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start(); echo session_id(); $_SESSION['x'] = "Y"; echo '<br>'; echo $_SESSION['x'];
```

if your cookies are disable then your session_id() create every time new. please make sure cookies are not disable.

Comment: Cookies are enabled, but the session cookie of this page is not saving in any of my browsers

Comment: please check the below link and do the configuration with session storing path in php.ini file with your server. I think temp folder is not set on server . https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: Sessions are stored in /var/lib/php/sessions/. Each time I refresh the page, a new session file is created.

Answer (score 0):

It's old, but the problem is very simple:
Your **cookie** need to be marked as **secure**!

Look this solution:
[PHP Session ID changing on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061324/1049870)

Answer (score -1):

Setting **$_SESSION** value **NULL** is working on this example.

```
<?php
session_start();
function errorMassage()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["errorMassage"])) {
        $outPut = "<div class =\"alert alert-danger\">";
        $outPut .= htmlentities($_SESSION["errorMassage"]);
        $outPut .= "</div>";
        $_SESSION["errorMassage"] = null;
        return $outPut;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by this example.