# How to fix session_id() always changed every request in ajax

Tags: php, session

It is safe to use session_id with a custom string?
Because my session_id generated a different random token after I reload my php project that cause session won't store

```
<?php
   session_id('r153vde76mulguktfamh9tsprk');
   session_start();
?>
```

Comment: Well if you used a fixed session ID, then all visitors of your site would share the same session ... _"Because my session_id generated a different random token after I reload"_ - then go investigate and fix that issue, instead of looking for workaround that make little sense to begin with.

Comment: Start by going through https://stackoverflow.com/q/2045550/1427878 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13306713/1427878